# How do I get an App ID and Masterkey for use with Parse-Server/Parse-Dashboard

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Where do I find an App ID, Master Key and File Key for use with Parse-Server and Parse-Dashboard?  Thanks.

Comment: Just make it up

Comment: I created a python script to output 16 random character string to simulate parse.com keys if you'd like to see

Answer (score 0):

Both are of your own choice, the App ID will be the identification you will choose for your App, since the Master Key will be a string that you will use as the password for this project (it is recommended to use a strong password)

Answer (score 0):

Make and use in parse-server. And use master key for parse-dashboard to give all permissions.

- Master Key: It gives all permissions. So do not use in your client side.
- App ID: Use this for clients. It can be checked with your `parse-server`.
- File Key: It is used only for prefix when you treat files.